# Remote Debugging .NET code Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, remote-debugging

I've been searching my hat off without any result, so a question for all of you guys:

I have a computer on domain A. On there I have a virtual machine running on domain B.

I've got visual studio installed on my computer but not on the vm => hence I want to debug a program running on the vm (domain B) which I've written in .NET with my visual studio installed on the pc (domain A).

When starting the vsmon program on the vm you have 2 options (windows auth. & no auth - native only).

When selecting no authentication, native only I get to see the processes in my visual studio and I can attach, but breakpoints are not being hit (because the PDB file does not contain native symbols, since it's written in .NET?)

When selecting windows authentication I can't connect and i get the error "logon failure"...

Any ideas / suggestions on this?

(btw, my firewall on the VM is turned off)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use remote debugging with windows authentication, because you want to debug a .NET application.
As to your authentication problem, please try [this solution/workaround](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2010/06/15/vs-remote-debugging-across-workgroups-or-domains.aspx).

The main info in this link is the following:

1. On both machines, create a local account with the same name and password: `net user username password /add`
2. On the remote machine, add that account to the local administrators group. `net localgroup administrators remotecomputername\username /add`
3. On the remote machine, either login with the new account or run msvsmon under it: `runas /user:remotecomputername\username "<full path>\msvsmon.exe"`
4. On the local machine, either login with the new account or run VS under it: `runas /user:localcomputername\username "<full path>\devenv.exe"`

Comment: thank you! a slightly painful solution, but glad to finally have one.

Answer (score 0):

with no authentication you cannot debug code remotely, you need to set windows authentication and secondly there will be same user group i.e with same domain user or you can make a local administrator user on both system and run the remote debugger and VS with administrator user